# Making a triple integral given a region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm doing some calculus' exercises and I need to find the bounds on a triple integral given some region. Well, I got it most of it, but when this region came out to me, I have some doubts:

$${{ \int_a^b}{\int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)}{\int_{z_1(x,y)}^{z_2(x,y)}f(x,y,z)dzdydx}}}$$

defined as:

$${{W:[(x,y,z)/(x^2+y^2)\le1,z\ge1,(x^2+y^2+z^2\le4]}}$$

I tried to do it, and I could find it:

$${{ \int_{-1}^1}{\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\int_{\sqrt{3-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}f(x,y,z)dzdydx}}}$$ but i don't know if this is correct and any help will be appreciated it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the $\;xy\,-$ plane you're on the unit disk $\;x^2+y^2\le1\;$ , so your limits for $\;x\;$ are correct and thus also for $\;y\;$. For $\;z\;$ you're between the plane $\;z=1\;$ and the sphere $\;x^2+y^2+z^2=4\;$, which gives us the limits for $\;z\;$ as $\;z=1\;$ from below and $\;\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\;$ from above.

Taking the above into account I think your limits are almost accurate, but observe that the restriction on the $\;xy\,-$ plane also restricts $\;z\;$ from above. Taking the circle $\;x^2+y^2=3\;$ on the plane $\;z=1\;$ will take us out of these limits, so just leave there $\;z=1\;$

Comment: Well, I make a little mistake where I defined $z\ge1$ when I supposed to write $z\ge0$ haha but, it's same thing that you just answer me.. Thank you :D

Comment: @alvaro.louzi Any time.